# action inside template is trying to find function in view as opposed to using routing definition

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to get the ember routing working following the guide at http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_transitions-and-urls
I am on 1.0.pre

However I am getting stuck on defining the action within my templatebar.

The error happens when I try to click on Read Article from my template bar it tries to find a showPost function inside my view as opposed to using the router, what target am I supposed to use for **target**? Also am I setting the context correctly?

**Error: assertion failed: Target <(subclass of Ember.View):ember337> does not have action showPost**

**EDIT:**
Project with error available at
https://github.com/newtonianb/todomvc/tree/master/dependency-examples/emberjs_require

Comment: If your application owns a router, then the {{action}} will automatically target it. Could you verify if the router is correctly instantiated ? I see you are using requireJs, or something like that, so I presume you have to depends on the router before calling App.initialize().

Comment: I'm confident the router works because from this other template it actually works properly without going to the view. See the edit above I added my applicationview and my view/posts which is what my action from templates/posts is getting sent to instead of the router. The router works for actions in the template of Options.Create()

Comment: Hmm, weird...Then all I can say, is to put a debugger; or breakpoint just before the assertion, and understand why the router either is not here, or why not used. It seems this is related to require stuff. I'm sorry, I can't help further. If you could fill a jsfiddle which illustrate, perhaps I could take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/newtonianb/CmpxP/

Comment: ? I wanted a jsfiddle of your example :p

Comment: I'm not sure how to recombine this project all together to show on jsfiddle in one page, it's quite fragmented now with requirejs, let me know!

Comment: Does it work with: `{{action showPost view.content href=true}}` ? (don't use `context=xxxx`)

Comment: Unfortunatey no, I had tried both ways and then added the context="" in a desperate attempt. The action is looking for the function showPost inside my view, I can actually catch it, could I just write a function in the view that then calls the route from there, if so how? I tried to do   showPost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('showPost') but then it gives me Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'transitionTo'

Comment: Your `itemViewClass` does not have any context (i.e. controller). So the view can't find the router. Could you try setting the `controller` property of each `itemViewClass` instance to the `controller` of the `CollectionView` ?

Comment: How do I do this exactly? Do I just add `controller: content` to itemViewClass? That gives 'content is not defined'

Comment: see @Ryan answer and my comment below. I guess the problem is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your view does not have a controller and router to send the action to. You can verify that your views controller and router exist by accessing `controller` and `controller.target` for the router.

In fact, looking at your code I would not expect the router to exist, because you are creating the controller by hand. The controller needs to know about the router so it can send events to it.

```
controller.connectOutlet({
  viewClass: PostsView,
  controller: PostsController.create(), // no target!
  context: context
})
```

Ember, by default, wires all of this togeather for you when your application initializes. This is where your contorllers get instantiated.

In fact, changing the above to something like this should solve your problem.

```
controller.connectOutlet({
  viewClass: PostsView,
  controller: router.get('postsController'), // this guy has target
  context: context
})
```

If this is still not working, can you please post a jsfiddle so we can edit this together.

Comment: oh yes, I found the problem, but was not in the right code location! I guessed it was due to the missing context in item views, but the context can come from its parent view (see http://goo.gl/wE85r). So the problem should come from the controller itself

Comment: Now that you mention it that makes sense! Let me give it a try after I cleanup, the project is huge mess with all the hacks I've been trying, will try it shortly after cleanup.

Comment: Good job Ryan :). @user391986 I think it's one of the reasons to use conventions is good, use controller.connectOutlet('posts', context'), and both the right (Posts)View and (Posts)Controller will be retrieved for you

Comment: I tried this but the problem I am not getting my data anymore when I do that method. The problem might be due with RequireJS integration so PostsController is a variable that represents app/controllers/posts. My PostsController is basically returning this.get("content")     return Ember.Controller.extend({ entries: function() { return this.get( 'content' ); }.property( 'content.remaining' ) });

Comment: The project was based on the todomvc emverjs + requirejs, so I was a able to reproduce the error from that repo. The source is available at https://github.com/newtonianb/todomvc/tree/master/dependency-examples/emberjs_require I think trying to learn requirejs a the same time as emberjs might have been a little too ambitious, I don't know how to debug the issues.

Comment: Please do not use ``PostsController.create()``. Use ``router.get('postsController')``. You need to use the controller instance that Ember has built for you. Also, you should make sure all of your controllers are defined at load time, this way Ember will build everything for you. I would recommend avoiding RequireJS until you have a better feel for Ember and its conventions.